# How to make use of a 3rd party plugin installed locally?

Tags: perforce, tycho

I have downloaded and installed the P4 Eclipse plugins (specifically com.perforce.team.core)
 and have written a plugin of my own to extend from theirs.

Using Tycho to automate the headless build is proving tough however. The build process downloads the Eclipse plugins for the build (good) but cannot download the P4 Eclipse plugins (bad) .. frustrating when they're in the local Eclipse installation.

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.":
>   ["Unable to satisfy dependency from
>   com.pushtechnology.p4tools.openFileSearch 1.0.0.qualifier to bundle
>   com.perforce.team.core 2010.1.275861.", "No solution found because the
>   problem is unsatisfiable."]

How can I direct Tycho to look to the local Eclipse installation, rather then floundering about on the Internet?

Comment: This doesn't work out of the box. You probably want this enhancement: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=363025

Answer (score 1):

Tycho needs to consume plug-ins and features from a p2 repository. Some versions of tycho permitted you to point to an eclipse installation by passing -Dtycho.targetPlatform=/path/to/eclipse to the maven command line. However this is deprecated and maybe even removed in the current tycho release.

Instead you have two options. The first is to run the [features and bundles publisher](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Publisher#Features_and_Bundles_Publisher_Application) to generate a p2 repository of everything in your eclipse installtion. This is a bit heavy handed and not a great solution.

The other option is to use the perforce update site. However looking at it, it appears to be an old style update site rather than a p2 repository. For tycho to use it you will first need to [mirror](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Repository_Mirroring) it to copy the plug-ins locally then run the features ans bundles publisher to convert it into a proper p2 repository. This would be my recommended approach.